# How can I create multiple constructors in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create different objects by calling constructors that have different number of parameters. How can I achieve this in Dart?

```
class A{
  String b,c,d;

  A(this.b,this.c)
  A(this.b,this.c,this.d)

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Constructor section of *Tour of Dart*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors).

Basically Dart doesn't support methods/constructor overloading. However Dart allows named constructors and optional parameters.

In your case you could have:

```
class A{
  String b,c,d;

  /// with d optional
  A(this.b, this.c, [this.d]);

  /// named constructor with only b and c
  A.c1(this.b, this.c);
  /// named constructor with b c and d
  A.c2(this.b, this.c, this.d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [factory constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors)

```
class A{
  String b,c,d;

  A(this.b,this.c,this.d)
  
  factory A.fromBC(String b, String c) => A(b, c, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the named constructor for clarity to implement multiple constructors for a class.

```
class A{
      String b,c,d;

      // A(); //default constructor no need to write it
      A(this.b,this.c); //constructor #1
    
      A.namedConstructor(this.b,this.c,this.d); //another constructor #2
    
    }
```

Comment: There will be an error "'A' is already declared in this scope" because you can't have 2 unnamed constructors.

Comment: I meant that Constructor `A();` is initialized by dart as a default one. No need to initialize it. thanks...

Comment: Not really, the default one is not generated anymore if there's an explicit one provided. If you try to instantiate A(), there will be an error: "Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 0 given."